# How to run sql script for Postgres in Docker?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am following this post to run SQL script to create default table.

Here is my docker compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - “3000:3000”
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: pgDockerfile
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_USER: test
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Here is my pgDockerfile

```
FROM postgres:9.6-alpine

# copy init sql
ADD 00-initial.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Here is my sql script

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    id text NOT NULL,
    title varchar(200) NOT NULL
);
```

I can build and run `docker-compose up`, and I see the following message:

```
postgres    | CREATE DATABASE
postgres    | 
postgres    | CREATE ROLE
postgres    | 
postgres    | 
postgres    | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00-initial-data.sql
postgres    | CREATE EXTENSION
postgres    | CREATE TABLE
postgres    | 
postgres    | 
postgres    | LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres    | LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres    | waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
postgres    | LOG:  shutting down
postgres    | LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres    |  done
postgres    | server stopped
postgres    | 
postgres    | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres    | 
postgres    | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-03-22 21:36:16 UTC
postgres    | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
postgres    | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres    | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

It seems like the db is shut down after the table is created. I think that’s the standard process for Postgres Docker but when I login to Postgres, I don’t see my table that is supposed to be there.

I login through

```
docker exec -it $(my postgres container id) sh

#su - postgres

#psql

# \d => No relations found.
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to create default data for Postgres.

Comment: You script are executed, looking the official image docs i found POSTGRES_DB parameter, maybe you need to setup this. Looking your configurations on docker-compose and dockerfile i can't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your docker works as intended, but it's not quite doing what you think. When setting `POSTGRES_USER`, but not `POSTGRES_DB`, the system will default to using the user name as database name, so your table is in the `test` database!

Using `\l` to list your databases will show the databases, and then you can use `\c test` to connect to the database. Once connected, `\d` will list your relations!